# Why am I getting different answers from grep -oc "foo" file and grep -o "foo" file | wc -l ? Which is correct?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

The question says it all really... I am trying to find the number of occurences of specific
strings in a large file.
The answers are similar.... like 50 000 or so with the pipe and 49 000 odd with just the plain grep - oc...

Can anyone explain why I am getting different answers, and which one would be correct?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Probably the larger number, as the other probably is the case where the string occurs more than once per line... maybe.

Comment: There's a bug against coreutils to fix this, though I'm not sure there is a consensus that the current behavior is wrong: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?33080 (I certainly think the current behavior is counterintuitive).

Answer (score 2):

`grep -c` counts only the matching lines whereas `grep -o` prints each matching part on a separate line which means that `wc -l` will print more "lines" than actually match.

As far as I can see, there is no effective  difference between `grep -oc` and `grep -c` because the suppression of printing means that there is no resulting effect of `-o` any more.

For example, printing a three line "file" with one double match and one single match:

```
$ printf 'foo foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | grep -oc foo
2
$ printf 'foo foo\nbar\nfoo\n' | grep -o foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Comment: Wow, I love how similar our answers are :) Foo Bar ftw ;)

Answer (score 2):

In `--only-matching` (`-o`) mode grep will sometimes output multiple lines for a single matching line.

```
alex@yuzu:~$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz"
foo
bar
baz

alex@yuzu:~$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | grep -o o  
o
o
```

But with `--count` (`-c`) it will count the number of matching lines.

```
alex@yuzu:~$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | grep -oc o
1
```

So `grep -o o | wc -l` is counting all the matches, even if there is more than one match in a single line.

Comment: I don't agree that the result from `-oc` is "correct", and it certainly seems to disagree with what the OP wants. If there are two occurrences on a line, the sought output is 2, not 1.